# NSFetchedResultsController - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate my TableView. I have an entity  "HubProfile" with attributes: "Name" & "HubID"

**Issue:** `NSFetchedResultsController` is coming `nil`. The weird part is that when I print `fetchedResultsController` in `viewDidLoad` & `cellForRowIndexPath` method -- it gives a value. But in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method, the `fetchedResultsController` is `nil` and the app crashes.

Also the data is already saved in CoreData. I have seen it in SQLite Browser -- so there is data to load

Can't seem to figure out why.

Below is my code:

```
 class StudentsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
 {
  let managedContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
  var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  //FETCH REQUESTS
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "HubProfile")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hubID = %@", hubID!)

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do
    {
        try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    }

    print(fetchedResultsController)  //THIS IS NOT NIL
    }

   //TABLEVIEWDATASOURCE PROTOCOL:

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(fetchedResultsController) // THIS IS NIL
    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
   }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! StudentsCell!
    print(fetchedResultsController)  //THIS is NOT Nil
    let hubProfile = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! HubProfile
    cell.nameLabel?.text = hubProfile.name 
    return cell
}}
```

Comment: So table view is trying to access 'fetchedResultsController' before any data is present in it. So what you can do is first check it is empty or not and put a tableview.reload after fetch in viewdidload. When data will be fetched then it will reload tableview.

Comment: And whenever you use optional value, try to unwrap safely then you won't get this error.

Comment: tried the reload data ..did not work..as I said in the viewDidLoad..I have put a print(fetchedResultsController)..That is working fine..The problem is only in the numberOfRowsInSection method.

Comment: Making `viewDidLoad` optional with all the following changes should fix the issue, out of curiosity I'd like to see the backtrace of the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` call where `fetchedResultsController` is nil, as well as whether it was called before or after `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: im not sure if i understood it correctly..I made the `fetchedResultsController` declaration optional..it still crashes...because "__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray' "...basically the `fetchedResultsController` is nil..

Answer (score 0):

The tableView may have loaded before the fetchResultsController has had a chance to load up. So reload the table as soon as you performFetch() as so:

```
  do
{
    try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

print(fetchedResultsController)  //THIS IS NOT NIL
}
```

Then in your tableView function check if the fetchedResultsController is nil, if it is then give it some other value (in this example, 0) and when the table reloads after the fetch is complete, the function will take the items from your fetchResultsController (when it is != nil):

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
           return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    }
```